# Is there any way to check the distance of an object to a locked layer in sketchapp?

Tags: layers, images, sketch-app, measurement

I am trying to see the distance of an object to a locked layer in sketchapp; however it just doesn't show the distance once the layer is locked. Do you know whether there is any way to measure the distance? Thanks millions ^^

Answer (score 2):

From the sketch documentation:

> With a layer selected, hold the Option key and hover over another layer. You will see that Sketch displays the distance between the two layers. When measuring against other layers, **you can also hover over the Layer List**.

What they fail to mention is that **this works for locked layers**: if you hold the Option key and mouse over the locked layer in the layers list, you'll see those familiar and oh-so-useful distance [Smart Guides](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/canvas/measuring/).